# Vue.js Update template from component method

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I want to update a components template when a certain method of the component is called. Just like the resolve function, or the Vue.compile render option, or the v-html binding option (but then with actually compiling the template).

How can i call the resolve function from the component method.

Is this possible and how should I do this with Vue.js?

Answer (score 1):

You define what's to be updated in the component's `data` function's return object's variable like [so](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Data). Data has to be a function if you are using a Component (eg. `Vue.extend`)

You then define a method and change `this.whateverYouNamedYourVariable` in the method, like [so](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Method-Event-Handlers).

And then you call the method either in `v-on` or programmatically. Here's a link to v-on event binding aswell: [Vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on)

And a quick example using webpack.

```
<template>
    {{me}}
    <button v-on:"changeMe">Click to change!</button>
</template>

<script>
 import 'vue' from 'vue'; 
 export default {
    name: 'VueEventBindDemo',
    data: function() {
        return { me: 'isMe'}
    },
    methods: {
        changeMe: function() {
           this.me = "isYou";
        }
    }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Thx for your answere, but how do I rerender the whole template like the [compile](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-compile) fn. So that in your example the v-on handler would also be applied by vue.

Comment: Have a read over https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html and see if that helps.

Comment: I have done that, but Vue probably wants me to make a new component for every template instead of dynamically loading in templates. What probably comes close to what I want is this http://jsfiddle.net/chrislandeza/syewmx4e/  but its deprecated in vue2

Comment: Compiles? They're not, but Vue is split to 2: the runtime only build and the compiler+runtime build, which one you get depends on how you download it.